# Ajax request windows phone 8

Tags: ajax, cordova, windows-phone-8

I'm developing an app with phonegap and I have an issue with the Windows Phone version.

I'm using an ajax request to get a json of data.

```
$.ajax({
            url: app.settings.structureUrl,
            crossDomain: true,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType:   "jsonp",
            localCache: app.settings.structureLocalCache,
            cacheTTL:   app.settings.structureCacheTtl,
            cacheKey:   app.settings.structureCacheKey,
            error: function ( data, textStatus, errorThrown ) { console.error( errorThrown ); dfd.resolve(); },
            success: function ( data, textStatus, jqXHR ) { app.structure = data; dfd.resolve(); }
        });
```

When I'm compiling on my registered phone everything work find.

But when I put on the market for beta the request doesn't work.

Do you have any idea ?

Thanks, Jonathan COING

Answer (score 0):

You probably missed to add ID_CAP_NETWORKING function in 'WMAppManifest.xml'. This function authorization is needed to communicate with the Internet. It is quite strange but it looks like the function authorizations are not checked when you test your app locally. On the Marketplace store web site you can see what functions your App requires. There it should mention: "data services".

Regards, Alexander